# Modify and Intergrate a custom MP3 Player

Tags: flash, open-source

This is a Flash MP3 Player I have found on internet, and I was looking for his .fla file so I can modify it and add some text on it.

Do you know where I can get the source of this flash player.

[image: MP3 Player]

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you saw that? There'd be a better chance of figuring out what it is by inspecting the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using today's technologies:  HTML5 audio

Example, the excellent jPlayer http://www.jplayer.org/